# Прерия - разбор слова по составу

Tags: этимология, морфемный-разбор

Добрый вечер!

Недавно столкнулась с интересным для разбора словом - *прерия* (окончание *-я*, корень - *...?*)

Есть ли однокоренные слова? И откуда вообще оно такое произошло этимологически?

Было бы здорово найти исконное слово, отсечь приставку *пре- (пра-)*, обнаружить "настоящий" корень и уже после этого всё-таки найти какие-то отдалённо связанные слова русского языка.

Спасибо.

---

Немного о происхождении (Aer):

prairies (англ.) -> prairie 'луг' (франц.) -> praerie (старофранц.) -> prataria (вульгарная латынь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Морфемный разбор: *прериj-а (прери-я)*.

Это слово заимствовано из английского *prairies*, восходящего к французскому *prairie* 'луг' (старофранцузское *praerie*), которое, в свою очередь, произошло от **prataria* из вульгарной латыни.

Общеупотребительных однокоренных слов нет; возможно, есть какие-то термины.

Comment: А французское слово откуда произошло? (Может ли *pra-* быть приставкой в изначальном слове?) 

Однокоренных нет ни в английском, ни во французском, ни в латинском? О_____О

Comment: @Александра дополнил ответ.

Comment: "prataria" тоже будет переводиться как "луг"? Как тогда будут звучать слова "луговой", "лужок", "лужайка" или ещё что-нибудь в таком духе? Потому что, если нет, допустим, общеизвестной приставки "пре-", то "пра-"-то уж точно есть и даже, наверное не одна... Будет весело, если она в один прекрасный момент уйдёт и тогда станет очевидным настоящий корень пра-слова.

Comment: @Александра да. На вульгарной латыни?.. Знаете, я не большой специалист в ней... нужно смотреть реконструкции. По-латински "луговой" будет *pratensis*. Приставка *пре* есть, равно как и *пра*. А искать праслова и пракорни такими методами -- гиблое дело, не советую))

Comment: Я задаюсь вопросами с самых что ни на есть дилетанских позиций, поэтому, действительно, могу забраться (или попросить забраться кого-нибудь другого...) в топь =) Поясню тогда, что вообще взбрело в голову: в русском языке слово "прерия" стоит обособленно и одиноко, и было бы здорово найти ему родственников и товарищей, попутно, может, отыскав несколько интересных и необычных фактов. Хочется вывести его из языковой изоляции в светское общество. Тем более, если у него глубокие корни. Тут же может вскрыться совсем неожиданное родство: вдруг, *прерия* окажется "матерью" *слона* или *Африки*...

Comment: @Александра ваше стремление похвально, но этимология, несмотря на то, что основывается в большей части на гипотезах, довольно точная наука, пространные размышления в ней -- последнее дело. Вывести слово "в светское общество" -- очень трудно, практически невозможно: должно произойти что-то, после чего все люди вдруг захотят говорить о прериях. Тогда появятся и производные. С Африкой и слоном прерии этимологически не связаны, 99,9 % :)

Comment: Согласна. Но может этот неразумный путь что-то выяснить настолько взбудоражит академическое общество, что люди захотят говорить о прериях на серьёзном уровне? хдд 

Потом, я верила, что ответ будет на поверхности, потому что на большое исследование, конечно, занятого лингвиста не спровоцируешь... 
Я подняла Вашу цепочку в текст вопроса, хотя может его следует посчитать решённым до "прерийного бума" =)

Comment: @Александра боюсь, на этот вопрос пока нет ответа :)

Comment: Что ж, это может обрадовать потенциальных филологов) Спасибо. Вопрос закрыт до появления новой информации.